# Is there a way to sort autocomplete results?

Tags: here-api

We use HERE Geocoder Autocomplete API. We'd like to show housenumbers first and only if there are no corresponding housenumnbers - streets. Is there a way to do so?
For example, for the query 2625 I get two results with "matchLevel": "houseNumber" and all other results with "matchLevel": "street", but here.com DB contains much more addresses with 2526, for example:
USA, CA, 95134, San Jose, 2625 Zanker Rd
USA, CA, Santa Clara, 95054, Santa Clara, 2625 Augustine Dr
USA, CA, Santa Clara, 95051, Santa Clara, 2625 Keystone Ave

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try to add **Country filter** parameter to your request as-

```
http://autocomplete.geocoder.api.here.com/6.2/suggest.json?app_id=XXX&app_code=YYY&query=2625&beginHighlight=<b>&endHighlight=</b>&country=USA
```

Comment: Here is my full query
http://autocomplete.geocoder.api.here.com/6.2/suggest.json?app_id=AP_ID&app_code=APP_CODE&maxresults=10&language=en&country=USA&prox=37.26,-121.8&query=2526

Comment: any ideas on how to sort results?

Comment: I set wrong q in my original query: it should be 2625, the same as in the question:
http://autocomplete.geocoder.api.here.com/6.2/suggest.json?app_id=AP_ID&app_code=APP_CODE&maxresults=10&language=en&country=USA&prox=37.26,-121.8&query=2625